# copy tableA to tableB if column in A is not duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to copy rows from `tableA` to a blank `tableB`.

`tableA` has a column `mytext` and the rows have duplicates from this column.

**question**
How can i copy from A to B where there are no duplicate rows from `mytext`? In other words if 2 or more rows have identical values in `mytext` keep the one with lowest id number and copy to `tableB`.

originally i tried to delete the duplicates but kept getting a an error `Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded from this sql command:`

```
DELETE n1 
FROM tableA n1, tableA n2 
WHERE n1.id > n2.id 
AND n1.mytext = n2.mytext
```

I am on `amazons` `RDS`

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
|   |     |     |      |       |
|   |     |     |      |       |
|   |     |     |      |       |
|   |     |     |      |       |
+------------------------------+ 
CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mytext` mediumtext,
    `morevar` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

this did not work, it did not catch the duplicates and simply copied all the values from tableA over to tableB

```
INSERT INTO tableB (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`mytext`,`morevar`)
SELECT DISTINCT tableA.id,tableA.fname,tableA.lname,tableA.mytext,tableA.morevar
FROM tableA
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this did not work"?  What was the result of the `INSERT` statement?  Also, it's unclear how you want to handle the duplicates.  If two rows have the same entry in the `mytext` field, which row do you want to insert into `tableB`?

Comment: does that select statement work if you run it without the insert?

Comment: @AustinLin the select does not select distinct from `mytext`,  it just outputs all the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO tableB (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`mytext`,`morevar`)
SELECT id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM tableA a
WHERE id = (Select Min(id) FROM tableA
            WHERE myText = a.mytext)
```

if you need to do this in batches... (edit myText criteria to control batches)

```
INSERT INTO tableB (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`mytext`,`morevar`)
SELECT id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM tableA a
WHERE mytext < 'j'
   And id = (Select Min(id) FROM tableA
            WHERE myText = a.mytext)

INSERT INTO tableB (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`mytext`,`morevar`)
SELECT id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM tableA a
WHERE mytext >= 'j'
   And mytext < 'r'
   And id = (Select Min(id) FROM tableA
            WHERE myText = a.mytext)

INSERT INTO tableB (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`mytext`,`morevar`)
SELECT id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM tableA a
WHERE mytext >= 'r'
   And id = (Select Min(id) FROM tableA
            WHERE myText = a.mytext)
```

Comment: do you think this is safe to run on something that has almost a million rows?  or should i add a `WHERE` and limit the id numbers?

Comment: the table is too big, keep getting `Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: Then do insert in batches of values of myText, see edited answer

Comment: thank you,  also is there a reason why `WHERE myText = a.mytext)` the T is camelcase on the first variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `GROUP BY mytext` to group the duplicate rows together.  The following should work:

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT * FROM tableA
  WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tableA GROUP BY mytext)
```